# How to use yield and Iron-router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, stack-trace, iron-router

So I am trying to do a basic meteor app at the moment.. here are the three files.

router.js:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate : 'layout',
    loadingTemplate : 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate : 'notFound'
});

Router.route("/", {
    name : "homeIndex",
    data : function() {
        return {
            message : "Welcome to the Rocket Shop"
        }
    }
});
```

index.html:

```
<template name="homeIndex">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
</template>
```

layout.html:

```
<template name="layout">
        {{> nav}}
        <div class="container">
            {{>yield}}
        </div><!-- /.container -->
</template>
```

When I go to localhost:3000 after starting the app I get a long stacktrace in my browser console and the body of the page does not load up.

```
22:35:57.444 Exception in callback of async function: MiddlewareStack.prototype.concat@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:303:7
RouteController.prototype._runRoute@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:542:11
Route.prototype.dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:856:10
Route/route@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:713:5
boundNext@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:425:16
Meteor.bindEnvironment/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?5deab0885176b44ccbbbf0b5101b065971c8f283:999:17
dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:449:3
RouteController.prototype.dispatch/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:393:7
Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?9309a5697855cef52b32921fbc9dcb1017c58b39:349:5
Tracker.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?9309a5697855cef52b32921fbc9dcb1017c58b39:237:5
Tracker.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?9309a5697855cef52b32921fbc9dcb1017c58b39:588:11
RouteController.prototype.dispatch/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:391:5
Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?9309a5697855cef52b32921fbc9dcb1017c58b39:615:12
RouteController.prototype.dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:390:3
Router.prototype.dispatch@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:1700:3
onLocationChange@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:1784:20
Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?9309a5697855cef52b32921fbc9dcb1017c58b39:349:5
Tracker.Computation@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?9309a5697855cef52b32921fbc9dcb1017c58b39:237:5
Tracker.autorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?9309a5697855cef52b32921fbc9dcb1017c58b39:588:11
Router.prototype.start@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:1777:31
Router/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:980:9
.withValue@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?5deab0885176b44ccbbbf0b5101b065971c8f283:971:17
withoutInvocation/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?5deab0885176b44ccbbbf0b5101b065971c8f283:428:26
Meteor.bindEnvironment/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?5deab0885176b44ccbbbf0b5101b065971c8f283:999:17
onGlobalMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?5deab0885176b44ccbbbf0b5101b065971c8f283:365:11
1 meteor.js:880:11
```

Does anyone possibly know what I am doing wrong? I am just following a pluralsight tutorial and have followed all of the directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question after searching around stackoverflow at other iron-router questions.. I have no idea why it worked, but it solved the issue. All I had to do was run:

```
meteor add ejson
```

and I no longer got my error.

Here is the question that answered my question (which was posted AFTER my question): 
[Iron:router 1.0.9 Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743925/ironrouter-1-0-9-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The exception isn't very relevant, but I see two possibilities:

- You forgot the `template` attribute in your `Route.route();`
- Your router configuration file isn't in the right folder

For the first one:

```
Router.route("/", {
    name : "homeIndex",
    template : "homeIndex",
    data : function() {
        return {
            message : "Welcome to the Rocket Shop"
        }
    }
});
```

For the second one: make sure your `router.js` file is in `client/lib/` folder.

Also, make sure that you have the `iron-router` package in the `.meteor/packages.js` file.

Comment: I believe router.js is supposed to be in just /lib/. Also, I added the template attribute and it didn't help. Hmm..