# Iron:router 1.0.9 Not working

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have recently installed a new meteor project, and added iron:router 1.0.9

But when i add route configurations i get a blank page and a console error of:

```
Exception in callback of async function: ReferenceError: EJSON is not defined
at MiddlewareStack.concat (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:303:25)
at RouteController._runRoute (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:542:17)
at Function.Route.dispatch (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:856:18)
at route (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:713:11)
at boundNext (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:425:31)
at Meteor.bindEnvironment (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?5deab0885176b44ccbbbf0b5101b065971c8f283:999:22)
at dispatch (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?ff70621b6c5f6a406edc60600c4b76126dae21d6:449:3)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_router.js?dd5fa02859b6335661b94134bd9903be8eecf44d:393:13
at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?9309a5697855cef52b32921fbc9dcb1017c58b39:349:36)
at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?9309a5697855cef52b32921fbc9dcb1017c58b39:237:10)
```

The only code i have is:

```
 Router.route('/', function () {
   this.render('home');
 }, {
   name: 'home'
 });
```

and

```
<head>
  <title>asm</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>


<template name="home">

  <h1>Home</h1>

  <p>
    Data Title:
  </p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually add the `ejson` package.

```
meteor add ejson
```

Comment: Thanks! I have never had to previously add ejson from a new meteor project.

Comment: This is likely due to the 1.2 transition, they're removing packages that were previously added by default to lighten Meteor initial JS footprint.

Comment: Yeah i have noticed some packages are being removed and also combined. I just though ejson was something almost all projects needed by default, but then again i can see some cases where its also not needed as well.