# Layout template will not yield

Tags: meteor, iron-router

This has been driving me nuts all morning. (Forgive me, I'm new to meteor.)  I have a fairly simple setup, following the habits described in Discover Meteor.

First, lib/router.js:

```
Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate: 'layout',
   loadingTemplate: 'loading',
   notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});

Router.route('/', {name: 'home'});

Router.route('profile', {name: 'UserProfile'});
```

Second, layout.html:

```
<template name="layout">
<div class="container">
    {{> navbar}}
    <div id="main">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

And finally, client/templates/users/user_profile.html:

```
<template name="UserProfile">
    <p>hello world</p>
</template>
```

If I place {{> userProfile}} in the layout it renders fine. But the Router will not do the deed for me, as it ought.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Typo: you have `UserProfile` in the route but the template name is `userProfile`

Comment: Corrected typo. Still not the solution. No change in output.

Comment: What comes back in the browser console? Might show some errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this issue too... You didn't post your console output, but here was my solution (I answered my own question):

[How to use yield and Iron-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731824/how-to-use-yield-and-iron-router/32745095#32745095)

In short this solved it for me: `meteor add ejson`